# How I make sticky nav bar which has responsive element without specific height above it?

Tags: sticky, navigationbar

So I have 100% of screen width header image at the top of the page and text element below the image. Below the text element I tried to make sticky navigation bar with this code:

```
$(function(){
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('#stickyribbon').offset().top;  
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop ) {
                    $('#stickyribbon').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
            } else {
                    $('#stickyribbon').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            }
    });
});
```

Problem is that sticky nav bar jumps to the top of the page already when I scroll down the height of the text element. So it totally ignores the header image. I have height auto for this image but it obviously does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. Solution was to make div with no height and padding-bottom as percentage of header image's height to its width and put the image in that div.